# Bingo game problem: all elements of array in another array

Tags: javascript

I have a small problem.
I have an array of 5 winning numbers and a random array draw of 10 numbers between 1 and 26.
If all the elements of the winning array are found in the draw array, it should return WIN and LOSE if they aren't.
It doesn't work. :(

```
function bingo(a) {
  let draw = [];
  let win = [2, 9, 14, 15, 7];
  for (let i = 10; i > 0; i--) {
    draw.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 26 + 1));
  }
  if (win.every((r) => draw.includes(r))) {
    return "WIN";
  } else {
    return "LOSE";
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: it works, it's just improbable that your random array will match all occurences inside of the win array

Comment: Also note that the 10 random numbers may not be distinct.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand from your question, you are just confused because of low probability of matching. You can test it with a constant array to see. However, I see that you are using argument `a` that does not have any functionality in your function since you define and use just arrays `draw` and `win` inside the function

```js
function bingo() {
  let draw = [];
  let win = [2, 9, 14, 15, 7];
  for (let i = 10; i > 0; i--) {
    draw.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 26 + 1));
  }
  //Here you can change draw with [2, 9, 14, 15, 7] to test
  if (win.every((r) => draw.includes(r))) {
    console.log(draw);
    return "WIN";
  } else {
    console.log(draw);
    return "LOSE";
  }
}

bingo();
```